# Solving a recurrence relation: $T(n^6) = 9T(n^{\frac{1}{6}}) + \log^2(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I would like to solve the relation:

$T(n^6) = 9T(n^{\frac{1}{6}}) + \log^2_2(n)$

Now upon searching, I found that such relations can be solved using iteration method and making a substitution, hence I tried substituting $m = \log_2 n$. This gives the relation:

$T(64^m) = 9T(2^{\frac{m}{6}})+m^2$. Am I solving this correctly?? How do I proceed further? Please help, I am not good at this.

Comment: That's a good start, now keep going. You can apply the recurrence to $T(2^{m/6})$ to express it in terms of $T(2^{m/216})$, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also, in the original question, the logarithm base was not given, I took it to be $2$ as done in some text online, would taking any other base be helpful? Like $6$ for instance?

Comment: The title does not appear to match the post. Qlso it may be easier to consider the function defined by $g(n)=T(2^{36^n})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(n^6) = 9T(n^{\frac{1}{6}}) + \log^2_2(n)
$

Put
$n = 2^{2^m}
$.
$\log_2n = 2^m
$.

Becomes
$T((2^{2^m})^6) 
= 9T((2^{2^m})^{\frac{1}{6}}) + 2^{2m}
$
or
$T(2^{6\cdot 2^m}) 
= 9T(2^{2^m/6}) + 2^{2m}
$.

Try
$n = 2^{6^m}
$.
$\log_2n = 6^m
$.

Becomes
$T((2^{6^m})^6) 
= 9T((2^{6^m})^{\frac{1}{6}}) + 6^{2m}
$
or
$T(2^{6^{m+1}}) 
= 9T(2^{6^{m-1}}) + 6^{2m}
$.

Let
$U(m)
=T(2^{6^m})
$.
Then
$U(m+1)
= 9U(m-1) + 6^{2m}
$.

This is readily solved.

Comment: @ClementC. If possible, can you look at the question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850519/reccurence-solution-no-using-master-theorem-that-tn-3tn-3n-log-n-t1-1