# Solving the recurrence: $T(n)=9T(n^{1/6})+\log^2(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion

I need to solve the following function using recurrence,

$$T(n)=9T(n^{1/6})+\log^2(n)$$

I know for a fact that this is done by making a change of variable but can someone tell me how to go about this? Like questions like this in general.

Comment: Try taking $g(m) = T(e^m)$ and put $n = e^m$  to get $g(m) = 9g(m/6) + m^2$.

Comment: Suspiciously close to the possible duplicate of [Solving a recurrence relation: $T(n^6) = 9T(n^{\frac{1}{6}}) + \log^2(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355827/solving-a-recurrence-relation-tn6-9tn-frac16-log2n)